# What is the pushforward of a function (not a vector)

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, differential-topology

If we have two manifolds $M$, $N$ with the map $f:M \to N$, then this induces a map between their tangent spaces $f_*:T_pM \to T_{f(p)} N$. By duality, another map exists $f^* : T^*_{f(p)}N \to T^*_pM$. This gives rise to the following relation:
\begin{equation}
f^* \omega(V) = \omega(f_* V)  \tag{1}
\end{equation}
for $V \in T_pM$ and $\omega \in T^*_{f(p)}N$.

Now what happens when $\omega$ is a smooth function on $N$, i.e. $\omega \in C^\infty(N)$? Then I think we have $f^* : C^\infty(N) \to C^\infty(M)$. If so, what does $f_*$ maps such that it is consistent with equation $(1)$?

Comment: Also, I wasn't sure what title I should use such that it reflects my question, so if anybody has a better suggestion, please feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f^*(g)=g\circ f$ when $g\in C^\infty(N)$. There are no tangent vectors here, since functions are $0^{\text{th}}$ order tensors.

Comment: Yeah, that is kind of why I am confused. If $f^*(g) = g \circ f$, then what happens to equation (1) in my original message? In other words, what do we take $V$ to be in the following equation: $f^*g (V) = g(f_*V)$? It doesn't make sense to take $V$ to be a vector, so I thought maybe $V$ should be a point on the $M$? Then we get: $f^*g (p) = g(f_*p)$, which I think is consistent, but I'm not sure. I hope you understand my confusion, but it is a bit difficult to explain for me.

Comment: I was guessing your confusion before I read this. I mean $f^*(g)(p) = g(f(p))$ for $p\in M$. In your original equation, the $p$ is still there. For $V\in T_pM$, $f^*\omega(p)(V)=\omega(f(p))(f_{*p}V)$.

Comment: Thanks! I think that actually clarifies a lot for me (although it may seem trivial).

Comment: You're very welcome. There's lots of room for confusion ;)

Answer (score 2):

In general there is no such thing as a pushforward map. In good situations, such a map exists, and roughly speaking it corresponds to "integration along the fibre" (also known as the Gysin map or the "wrong way map").

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As Ted Shifrin has pointed out, we do get $f^* g - g \circ f$ where $g \in C^\infty (N)$. I guess I'm trying to figure out how that changes equation (1) in my original question? I have the feeling that we should get: $f^*g (p) = g(f_*p)$, because this appears to be consistent to me, but I'm not sure. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Given a smooth function $\omega$ on $N$, by right compositing with $f$, we get $f^*(\omega)=\omega\circ f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, a smooth map on M. Taking the derivative of this function at a point $p\in M$, we get $D\omega_{f(p)}\circ f_*$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
D(f^*(\omega))(p)=D\omega_{f(p)}\circ f_*
\end{equation}
Hope this might be relevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm a bit confused by your notation, because I'm a physics student (don't hold it against me please ;) ). Are you saying we should get: $f^*g (p) = g(f_*p)$ for $p \in M$ and $g \in C^\infty(N)$?

Comment: Please don't write $\omega$ for a function!

Comment: You need to take the derivative of $f^*\circ g$. By the way that $D$ means taking derivative of a function(some use $d$ for this). In our case for $f^*\circ g$, $D(f^*(g))(p):T_pM\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @BigBadBat ok thanks. That notation is very confusing for me (I have seen it before), because for me that notation is used for a covariant derivative. Either way, thanks again for your time and your answer.